# Convert HEX characters to TArray<Byte> for sending to comm port

Tags: android, delphi, serial-port

I recently obtained a comm port library for Android from [ComPort for Android USB Serial](https://www.winsoft.sk/acpusbser.htm).

This has so far enabled me to send characters to a LoRa device connected via an OTG cable to the device. Now I want to send configuration Hex to the device. I was able to achieve the goal in VCL using a [ComPort Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/) like so:

```
procedure TForm1.btnSendHexClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  S, Str: AnsiString;
begin
  S := 'AFAF0000AF8002020000910D0A';
  Str := HexToString(S);
  ComPort.Write(Str[1], Length(Str));
end;

function TForm1.HexToString(S: String): String;
var
  tmp: AnsiString;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result:= '';
  for i := 1 to length(S) div 2 do
  begin
    tmp := Copy(S,(i-1)*2+1,2);
    Result := Result + AnsiChar(StrToInt('$'+ tmp));
  end;
end;
```

Now I want to do the same thing in Android FMX;

This is my attempt (that doesn't work) Clearly my understanding of how these things need to be done, is too shallow. Any assistance is appreciated!

```
procedure TFormMain.btnSendHexClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Line, Str: String;
  Buffer: TJavaArray<Byte>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Line := 'AFAF0000AF8002020000910D0A';
  Str := HexToString(Line);
  Buffer := TJavaArray<Byte>.Create(Length(Str));
  i := 0;
  while i < Length(Str) do
  begin
    Buffer[i] := Ord(Str[i]);
    Inc(i);
  end;
  SerialDevice.syncWrite(Buffer, 1000);
end;

function TFormMain.HexToString(const S: String): String;
var
  LOutput: TBytes;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(LOutput, Length(S) div 2);
  Len := HexToBin(PChar(S), 0, LOutput, 0, Length(LOutput));
  Result := TEncoding.ASCII.GetString(LOutput, 0, Len);
end;
```

And yes, the `SerialDevice.syncWrite` function accepts a `TJavaArray<Byte>` as it's first parameter. The second parameter is a timeout (milliseconds) value.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: HexToString makes no sense at all. Do you mean HexToBin? A string is not an array of bytes.

Comment: In the VCL version, it really IS hextoString. Maybe the function could be named more appropriately in the Android version. But that doesn't help me solve the problem.

Comment: @DSM. When the LoRa device receives the correct config characters, it responds with a hex configuration string. This, as I said, works on the VCL. In the Android implementation, the device sends the characters to another LoRa. ie. it doesn't recognise them as a configuration setting.

Comment: It makes no sense for you to use a string to hold a byte array. That's your basic problem. So many Delphi programmers just don't seem to get that a string is not a byte array. It's like we are being taken over by PHP programmers! Convert it to a byte array instead using, e.g. `HexToBin`: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.HexToBin

Comment: I already did that. Are you saying i can leave out the TEncoding steps?

Comment: You ask how to convert from a hex string to a byte array. But then you don't do that. You instead try to convert to a string. What do you actually want to do. Can't you see that `LOutput` contains a byte array?

Comment: I've got it now. Thanks for your help David!